# Как с помощью bat-файла запустить программу по сети?

Tags: windows, bat

Как с помощью bat-файла запустить программу по сети?

Например, я по сети выполняю команду:

taskkill /s 10.10.10.10 /IM Name.exe

Эта команда завершает процесс Name.exe. Работает. А как снова запустить этот процесс?  Либо файл exe (расположение файла известно).

Comment: Аналогично завершению: start 10.10.10.10\procPath\proc.exe. Или вам нужно запускать на удаленной машине?

Comment: @Ildar да,  удаленно

Answer (score 4):

В составе [Sysinternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062) есть утилита psexec:

```
psexec \\10.10.10.10 <путь_к_программе_на_удаленной_машине>
```

(возможно, вам потребуются опции `-u`, `-p` для указания имени пользователя/пароля для подключения к машине)

Comment: эту утилиту достаточно установить на мою машину? Либо на обе нужно?

Comment: @Владимир только на вашу